# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'products')

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to get products, then check if the product pId is in an array, and filter if it is.
I get an error when i soft refresh of 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined' (reading 'products'), almost like my 'this.products' isnt populated yet when computed is trying to get the data. Tried adding some if statements to check data is there but no luck.

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      popular_products: [],
      products: [],
    }
  },

  computed: {
    bestsellers() {
      const keywords = this.popular_products
      let array = []
      for (var index = 0; index < keywords.length; index++) {
        const keyword = this.products.data.products.product.filter(
          (product) => product.pId == keywords[index].ProductNumber
        )
        array = array.concat(keyword)
      }
      return array
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    axios
      .get(
        'https://myurl/admin/api/collections/get/popularproducts?token=account-9306f9192049d3c442e565f2de5372'
      )
      .then((response) => (this.popular_products = response.data.entries))

    axios
      .get('https://myurl/products.json')
      .then((response) => (this.products = response))
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```js
let keyword = this.products.data.products.product.filter(product => product.pId == keywords[index].ProductNumber);
```

more specific with this read: `data.products`.

You see, `computed` property `bestsellers` is evaluated before your `axios` calls are finished.

Because of that, Vue can't find `products` in `data` because your `this.products` doesn't have `data` key.

The best solution would be to change this assignment:

```
- .then(response => (this.products = response)); // delete this line
+ .then(response => (this.products = response.data.products)); // add this line
```

**Update** After comment.

```js
if (this.products.product) {
  return this.products.product.filter(...)
} else {
  return []
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its still doing it though. Ive changed it in the axios call to what you said and then the computed filter is now et keyword = this.products.product.filter(prod.... im getting 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')'

Comment: That is because product is `undefined`. Try adding `if` statement. I have updated my answer. Or assign `response.data.products.product` to `this.products` if you are using only that property. Good luck 

Comment: All good bud thank you. Any idea at all why the facebook app returns no products? It only seems to be an issue with products, other data is okay but the other data comes from the backend headless cms where as product data is from a json file. Its all the same domain so shouldnt be a CORS issue...

Comment: @jord49 sorry no. I have never tried their API ‍♂️